# Having trouble with binary tree

Tags: c

I can't figure out this error in my code:

```
error: invalid operands to binary < (have ‘Flight’ and ‘NodeT’)
 if ( flight < *p)
             ^
```

I am trying to make a binary tree and create a search for it:

```
NodeT *insertT(NodeT *p, Flight flight)
{

if ( p == NULL )
{
    p = malloc ( sizeof ( NodeT ) ) ;

    (p) -> pLeft = NULL ;
    (p) -> flight;
    (p) -> pRight = NULL ;
}
else/* search the node to which new node will be attached */

{
    /* if new data is less, traverse to left */
if ( flight < *p)
        insert ( &( (p) -> pLeft ), flight ) ;

else /* else traverse to right */

        insert ( &( (p) -> pRight ), flight ) ;
}



}
```

I've tried changing in and adjusting the nodes.

Comment: `flight` is a `Flight`, and `*p` is a `NodeT`. They're different data types. How is `<` supposed to compare different data types? It's like trying to compare `3.14 < "duck"`.

Comment: What does the NodeT struct look like? By the way, the line `(p) -> flight;` does nothing. And also, after you create a new node, the result is thrown away without any effect.

Comment: typedef struct NodeT
{
    Flight   flight;                        // contains flight information
    struct NodeT *pLeft;                    // points to the left node
    struct NodeT *pRight;                   // points to the right node
} NodeT;

Comment: What do you believe that statement `(p)->flight;` will do?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to compare two different types -- `Flight flight` and `NodeT *p`.

Based on your code, it would appear that you need to change

```
if (flight < *p)
```

to

```
if (flight < p->flight)
```

Comment: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘Flight’)
     if (flight < *(p->flight))
                  ^